# I was wondering or I am wondering?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, present-tense, simple-past

In a job interview, I want to ask the interviewer about work hours. We are talking in the present. In this case which sentence is correct, and why?

> 1. I was wondering, what are the work hours?
> 2. I am wondering, what are the work hours?

Comment: If you want to know the working hours, ask "What are the working hours? "

Comment: Are you **still** wondering?

Comment: As an aside, it's either "I was wondering what the work hours are.", or "I was wondering, what are the work hours?", but not a mixture of both.

Answer (score 0):

2nd sentence is correct because you are talking of present.